# Along the street vs. Down the street

Tags: word-choice

> I often see this man. He is walking **along/down** the street.

What are the differences between *along* and *down* in this context?

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us what research you have done on your own, and which of the two choices you think is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your usage

> along the street
>   They rode their bicycles **along** the street.

may mean "***in*** *the street*" or "***beside*** *the street*", whereas

> down the street

will mean "***in*** *the street*" or some distance "***further along*** *the street*"

> The house is **down** the street.
>   Just drive further **down** the street and you'll see it.

Answer (score -1):

> Along the street.

In parallel with the full length of the street.

> Down the street.

If the street is not perfectly flat, when you're walking down the street, you're heading for its lower end.

> Up the street.

If the street is not perfectly flat, when you're walking up the street, you're heading for its higher end.

Comment: Up and down in this context don't refer to elevation.  They both mean further on.

Comment: "Up" and "down" are sometimes relative to city centres, too.  You'd walk "down" the street toward downtown (the central business district), and "up" the street toward the suburbs (or toward uptown, in cities that have such areas).

Comment: I agree with the other two commenters. My bicycle can be coasting downhill, even as I am riding "up" the street.